# Asynctask from non-UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, compression

I used compressed image library : https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor.
This library must run UI thread but compress function is inside non-Ui thread. So I moved this function inside asynctask.

Is this the right way and do you have any other idea? Use asynctask `execute()` correctly or should I use `executeOnExecutor()` or not use `get()` function?

```
public static class compressFile extends AsyncTask<Void, File, File> {

        @Override
        protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {

            File thumbFile = null;

            try {

                thumbFile = new Compressor(MyApplication.getContext())
                        .setMaxWidth(width)
                        .setMaxHeight(height)
                        .setQuality(quality)
                        .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                        .compressToFile(new File(path), " " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Mylog.printStackTrace(TAG + " error", e);
            }

            return thumbFile;
        }

    }
```

> > compress image usage in non-UI thread:
>
> ```
> File compressedBigFile = new compressFile().execute().get();
> ```

Comment: A sidenote: `MyApplication.getContext()` implies that you have a static reference to your application context, which is not a good practice. You should instead pass context as a parameter in the `AsyncTask` constructor and keep it using a weak reference.

Comment: Ok thank you ,after that I will write as you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not right.  NEVER use AsyncTask.get on the UI thread.  Doing so forces the UI thread to wait for the result.  This is equivalent (actually slightly worse) than not using a thread at all.  The correct thing to do is to put any code that requires the result in onPostExecute of the AsyncTask so it is run when the task finishes, and if necessary put up a loading UI while it processes.